# Opening an external URL in NextJs and Strapi

Tags: next.js, strapi

Currently I'm trying to redirect the user to a particular link that is filled in as a data value in my CMS which is Strapi in my case. I'm using `<a href>` to redirect the user but doing this takes me to this URL `http://localhost:3000/www.google.com`. How do I get rid of the localhost part from my URL.
Additionally I've also tried using next/link, but I get the same output.

Currently this is my code:

```
<a href={item.LinkedIn} target="_blank">
                            <img
                              style={{
                                height: "20px",
                                width: "20px",
                                backgroundColor: "white",
                              }}
                              src="linkedin.svg"
                            />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems right. Can you check the value in `item.LinkedIn`. If it is `http://localhost:3000/www.google.com`, try to pass only `www.google.com` with split.

set `VERCEL_URL=http://localhost:3000` in `.env.local` file,

then

```
host_url = `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/`
<a href={`${item.LinkedIn.split(host_url)[1]}`} target="_blank"></a>
```

note:

- `VERCEL_URL` will be available automatically in vercel for preview and prod environments [doc](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables#system-environment-variables)
- it is good to add `rel="noopener"` for links that redirects to new window

Comment: This is actually giving me a /undefined for some reason. I have added a sandbox of my output: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fog-v6hhr?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: in question you had specified you wanted to remove localhost part from the url. hence the split method in [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-feynman-lc40r?file=/src/App.tsx). But in the sandbox, we are passing only www.google.com. in that case, split wont be needed. check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-rain-hdfro?file=/src/App.tsx) - no extra processing

Comment: Yes I opened yours and you are getting the same output where it puts your localhost before www.google.com. I want that localhost part to go so I can go to the actual specified website

Comment: ok, i think i got :D   you need to add `https` to the link for anchor tag to redirect to an external site. check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-rain-hdfro?file=/src/App.tsx)